# React Native - Default style for elements

Tags: react-native

Is there a way in React Native to set the style for standard elements without adding a style tag to each and every one? Like for example I want to alter the style for these:

```
<Text>This is test</Text>
<Text>This is also text</Text>
<Text>And so is this</Text>
```

As I understand it the only way to say a margin indent is to do this:

```
<Text style={styles.indentText}>This is test</Text>
<Text style={styles.indentText}>This is also text</Text>
<Text style={styles.indentText}>And so is this</Text>
```

In ordinary website CSS you can obviously just set some styles for all HTML elements without needing to add a class or ID to them. How is it done in React Native?

Answer (score 1):

You can set an abstraction layer just for it:

```
IndentedText = React.createClass({
  render: () {
    <Text style={styles.indentText}>{this.props.text}</Text>
  }
})
```

And then in your other components:

```
<IndentedText text={"This is a text"} />
<IndentedText text={"This is also a text"} />
<IndentedText text={"And so is this"} />
```

Comment: So its really not possible to give default style settings for the generic elements? Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I wouldn't want to modify the original Text component. Just use a custom component like I suggested and you should be set. I am sure you won't want all of your text components to have the exact same style...

Comment: Well I just thought it would be possible purely with a css style. Like in webdesign:   div {margin-left: 20px;}  With no need to alter any of the main displayed elements. I guess it can't be done with React Native.